# check for last div with a specific id on a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="div-1">1st div</div>
<div id="div-2">2nd div</div>
<div id="div-3">3rd div</div>
<div id="div-4">4th div</div>
<div id="div-5">5st div</div>
```

How can I test if 5st div is the last div with the id of div-%s on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
var lastDivId = $('div:last').attr('id');

if(lastDivId === 'div-5'){
//the last div is the one with id = div-5
```

EDIT - even better (in this way you consider only divs with the `id` that starts with `div-`:

```
var lastDivId = $('div[id^=div-]:last').attr('id');

if(lastDivId === 'div-5'){
//the last div is the one with id = div-5
```

Comment: This will tell you if that's the last DIV, not the last DIV with that naming convention.

Comment: i will generate the div-%s dynamically so it will not work checking for div-5... i need to access if last parent or something

Comment: @Mythriel if you just need to access the last id with that naming convention, use  `$('div[id^=div-]:last')`

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient, but at least it should work.

```
var i = 0,
    el;
do {
   el = document.getElementById( 'div-' + i );
   i += 1;
} while( el );
// now el contains a reference to the last div element with an id of your syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This. It will select the last div with the text `div-` in its id and tell you its id. Just

```
if ($('div[id^=div-]:last').attr('id')=='div-5'){
    alert('div 5 is the last div');
else
    alert('div 5 is NOT the last div');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
   alert($("div:last").attr("id"));
});
```

will give you last div it

Edit:

you can also get last child as

```
$("div :last-child")
```

hope this help............

Comment: This does not take into account the naming convention. It finds the last div on the page, not the last div with the id `div-#`

Comment: you can place a parent div above all and then get last child :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way

```
if ($('#div-5 + div[id^="div-"]').length === 0) {
   /* div-5 is last div */
}
```

so you could avoid to also call `.attr()` method

Answer (score 0):

I would take the container element of the divs and use the pseudo selector :last to get the last child.

```
var res = ($("body div:last")[0].id  ==  "div-5") ?  alert('last div is div-5') : alert('last div is not div-5');
```